# Combining multiple attributes of a single layer

Tags: arcmap, fields-attributes, arcgis-10.6

I'm making a map that consists of 500x500m grids. These grids have four attributes that are of importance to me, of which 2 attributes are "linked".

Three of these attributes ("Nature", "Protection" and "Calculating") are binary (0 or 1), and the fourth ("Calculated_Points") are decimal values.

When I say two of these values are linked I mean to say that when one binary value ("Calculating") is equal to 1 there is a value in the decimal attribute ("Calculated_Points"). If "Calculating" equals 0, there is no value in "Calculated_Points".

What I need to display on my map is rather straight forward, but I can't seem to get it into ArcMap.

- For all cases where "Protection" equals 1 I want to fill the grids with a dotted transparant pattern.
- For all cases where "Nature" equals 1 I want a dark green fill.
- For all cases where "Calculating" equals one, I want to display a sliding color scale based on the value of "Calculated_Points", grouped in 5 categories. (0-100; 100-250; 250-500; 500-750; >750)

I know there is the option to map Multiple Attributes, but I can't seem to get it done with categories of my decimal attribute.

Comment: Coming to think of it, I could just duplicate my layer 3 times, and make a symbology for each layer, and stack them in the right (visibility) order. This would be a workaround, but I'd love to have the dots in the same colour as the background.